# CodeLite IDE V6.1 : highlight selected word/string in file

Tags: codelite

were can i enable this feature? There is no change when i enable the checkbox under Editor Settings->Bookmarks->"... highlit matching words".

Any hint will be welcome.

Best Regards

Lars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should be enable by default. which OS Are you using?
there is a known issue on osx where it does not work out of the box and needs to be disabled and re-enabled .

this can be done from the main toolbar, click the icon that looks like an ink and brush

Eran

Comment: That it. I only browse the menu-bars for a corresponding entry and don't look at the icons in the toolbar. Thanks a lot.